# study the differentiability of this function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ be a square matrix of size $n^2 $ over $\mathbb R$, i.e $A\in M_{nn}(\mathbb R)$. Define the function $ h:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ defined by $ h(x)=x^tAx$.

How can I find the cases in which $h$ is a differentiable function?

Comment: I think, you have $h:R^{n}\rightarrow R$...$h$ is a quadratic function and hence differentiable...where is the problem?

Comment: @Trafalgaw If $x$ is $n\times 1$, then $x^TAX$ is $1\times 1$, therefore the codomain of $h$ should be $\Bbb R$.

Comment: You are right, Thanks!

Comment: @Trafalgaw You can edit the question.